# Measuring inductance of motor coil with low Q factor

Tags: circuit-design, inductance, bridge, inductance-measurement

I have a motor coil that I suspect has an inductance outside the nominal range. I wanted to use a Maxwell-Wein bridge to determine the inductance of the bad coil. The main concern I have is that, as I understand it, the MW Bridge requires Q factors in the range of 1-10. Some quick calculations of our Q factor using the coil (using the equation \$Q = \frac{\omega L}{R}\$, as determined from the [Wikipedia Entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_bridge)) led to values on the order of \$10^{-3}\$.

What I would like to know is if there exist any other bridge methods (or any methods in general) for determining unknown inductance given known resistance, capacitance, frequency, etc... that would be suitable for such a low Q factor? I've looked around and seen the concept of an [Anderson's Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson%27s_bridge). Would such a thing be suitable in your opinion? I see there is no reference to a Q factor range.

Comment: What frequency did you use for your calculation of Q?  Perhaps not ideal, but you could increase the frequency enough to bring Q above 1 just for this measurement.

Comment: What is the DC resistance, and what inductance do you expect?

Comment: Unless you remove the rotor, the stator coils will  have inductance that depends very much on the rotor orientation, and of course the rotor windings' inductance depends on the stator orientation.

Comment: @evildemonic I thought the same, however the article I read mentioned that I should use frequencies that are consistent with the frequencies experienced by the coil in the instrument. These frequencies are (depending on the resolution of the scan) 1.83, 3.4, 6 and 11.83 hz. In your experience is this constraint strict or can it be bent a bit?

Comment: @Mattman944 The measured resistance is 2.7 Ohms and the nominal inductance in air is 0.7 uH and in motor is 1.7 mH

Comment: If you are just trying to sniff out a bad coil, go ahead and increase the frequency, you don't care about the actual exact inductance at the used frequency.  Also pay attention to what @Whit3rd said.

Comment: @evildemonic Well, we know the coil is bad due to performance in the system but we would like to get an accurate reading of the inductance to determine if aberrant values could be what's contributing to the problem we have been having consistently with these motor coils. Do you think we would still get an accurate reading for the inductance if we simply cranked the frequency?

Comment: I do think it will be accurate enough.  Especially if you are comparing one coil to another and using the same conditions.  The reason you typically use the working frequency is because parasitic losses don't scale linearly with the frequency, but the results will still be pretty close in most cases if you don't get too crazy with it.

Comment: @evildemonic Okay thank you! So it would probably be good to check out a good motor coil as well for reference to see how far we are off, if we aren't getting an absolutely accurate value. As we intended on comparing it to the nominal value on the spec sheet. I appreciate your insight.

Answer (score 0):

Motor issues related to inductance:

1. Not enough turns: unlikely.
2. Shorted turns.
3. Magnetic path cracks, etc.

The various bridges can be very accurate. They aren't that hard to create, and since I like working in the lab, I would try several methods. Since you have a good motor to compare with, you can verify the test method.

Or, since you seem to be looking for gross issues, you might try a simple divider. It isn't nearly as accurate as a bridge, but it is simpler.

The resistance of the inductor must be small compared to the series resistor. The frequency must be low enough so capacitive parasitics aren't a factor.

This method works for most power supply inductors, not sure how well it will work on a motor.

Adjust the frequency until the voltage on the inductor is the same as the voltage on the resistor. The voltages will be out of phase, so you want the inductor voltage to be 0.707 multiplied by the input voltage. Use a scope, most meters won't be accurate at these frequencies.

\$ X_L = 2 \pi fL \$

When: \$ X_L = R_S \$ :

\$ L = \frac{R_S}{2 \pi f} \$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDZWcn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Test with a 1 mH inductor from my parts box. Rs = 100 ohms.

Inductor voltage = 0.707 * input voltage when f = 16.1 kHz.

\$ L = \frac{100}{2 \pi (16100)} = 0.989 mH \$

Answer (score 0):

Any impedance divider will do, but which one you choose depends on what test equipment you have, and what part of the operating range you want to be most sensitive to.

I have a number of calculators collected on my website here: 
[LC Resonance | Calculators | Seven Transistor Labs](https://%20https://www.seventransistorlabs.com/Calc/RLC.html)

By the way, the calculations are easily found under the Sources tab (hit F12, view sources, RLC.js).

The first two are just for reference, working with L, C and Z.

The third, **L or C by Resistor Divider**, uses a divider between a known (AC) voltage source, a known impedance (resistor), and the DUT (Device Under Test).  The resulting amplitude is measured.  This is an ambiguous measurement, as the phase shift could be positive or negative, and we don't know which from a magnitude measurement; we also don't know how much it's shifted by.  We assume the maximum case, and thus calculate an equivalent lossless inductance or capacitance.  Which of course means this method will read in error when the DUT is quite lossy (roughly speaking, say 10% error for Q ~ 10, and so on), i.e. the phase shift is closer to zero.

**Vector Impedance by Resistor Divider:** we can improve the measurement by including phase.  If we use an oscilloscope to measure the generator and DUT voltages simultaneously, and measure the phase angle between them, we can make a vector measurement.  The additional parameter covers for the missing degree of freedom, and a reasonably accurate complex-valued measurement is possible.  Note that scopes generally don't measure angle very accurately (within a few degrees, perhaps), so this method is good up to comparable error -- a few degrees corresponds to the uncertainty whether a low-loss inductor has a Q of + or - 100, for example.[1]

**Frequency and Q Factor:** we can cancel out the bulk of inductive or capacitive reactance with a resonant pair, and get a more accurate measure of losses in the high-Q condition.  This requires a low-loss companion; capacitors generally have higher Q than inductors, so measuring an inductor is not too difficult, but measuring a capacitor's loss accurately, requires calibrating an inductor first, or using a *really really nice* one.

**Parasitic Capacitance by Difference** can be ignored for present purposes, but is useful for measuring networks that are already resonant at or near a frequency of interest.

**L and Q by Matching Capacitor** is a variation on the above, using a capacitor instead of a divider resistor; the low loss allows more power to be deposited into the load, and may lead to a more precise measurement as well.

---

These are basically all half-bridge methods; full-bridge methods aren't so important anymore these days, as 1. it's inconvenient to set up balancing impedances (you need an array, or adjustable values of, resistors and inductors or capacitors), 2. nulling measurements are inconvenient or tedious, and 3. direct measurement of the divider ratio is easy enough.

Or if you like -- the other half is replaced by the voltmeter or oscilloscope, which you can imagine as nulling against a voltage source of the measured value.  Give or take whether its phase is known (for a magnitude measurement, we can assume that the phase automatically tracks to give the minimum reading, but that that phase angle is unknowable).

The choice of network, then, comes down to what aspects of the impedance we're interested in: high or low frequency, wide or narrow range, sensitivity to reactance or resistance, precise phase angle, etc.

As for choice of test equipment, mind that voltmeters are not created equally.  A typical DMM has a bandwidth of a few kHz; the above methods (except vector) are only usable with a magnitude measurement (any normal peak, average or RMS reading voltmeter) within their bandwidth.

Also mind that DUTs need not be well-behaved.  Particularly with iron-cored components (transformers, motors), the inductance can vary with amplitude; and brushed motors for example can depend on angle (sometimes the brushes are shorting across segments, sometimes they make poor contact, etc.).  Lossy components in general vary with frequency, so it matters what you measure it at.

A motor might well be measured with a signal generator at 1kHz, and this is a common enough measurement that you may find it in the datasheet reported as such.  Most simple LCR meters also do this; but beware that they may do an arbitrary method (e.g. variable frequency oscillator), non-sinusoidal waveforms, etc., and you should choose a meter that says how it performs the measurement.  If you have a signal generator and oscilloscope as most engineers do, the above methods are simple to perform.

Mains frequency can even be used as the source, for applicable cases, but mind that because the frequency is so low, the motor may begin to move or vibrate during the test (the resulting motion and EMF contributes error to the measurement), and you'll probably need a transformer to keep the signal level modest (say, a 6.3V transformer, or a variac, or both).

---

[1] Yes, negative Q -- which would mean negative resistance, or the device is apparently capable of amplifying incident energy, rather than absorbing it.  In the impedance/admittance space, continuity through ± zero, in one domain, is equivalent to continuity through ± infinity in the other, and vice versa.  Ambiguity over phase, for a nearly-pure component, is simply saying it's ambiguous whether it's lossy or "gainy".  We can rule out gain for physical reasons, but the measurement itself is perfectly reasonable, given such error, and this understanding.